# How can i get facebook xid and href comments after July changes?

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-comments, xfbml

Today, I've just updated the Comments plugin, now based on `href` property, after changes introduced by "July 2013 Breaking Changes".

Using the new `href-plugin` I no longer see the *xid*-comments, but I can see new posted comments.

I've read and followed the trick explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437385/will-xid-based-fbcomments-be-lost-on-june-1st) but nothing changed.

I've made some tests on my own and these are the results:

Using the new plugin I get only the comments with `href` property;

```html
<fb:comments href="http://www.mywebsite.com/post/2"></fb:comments>
```

If I revert the new plugin with the old one (I mean `fb:comments` with `xid` property) I get back my old comments, but not the `href-posted` comments;

```html
<fb:comments xid="2" url="http://www.mywebsite.com/post/2"></fb:comments>
```

If I force to send `xid` and `href` properties together in `fb:comments`, by manually changing the plugin, I got only the new comments;

```html
<fb:comments xid="2" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/post/2"></fb:comments>
```

Even If I add `migrated=1` in these cases, the results are as described previously.

Of course I've both `xid` and `href` values related to a page.

Is there a way to "import" the `xid-comments` into the `href-comments`, or to get all comments together?

Comment: Can you put your url in :- 

 http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=<url> 

and see what comments it is showing. Looks more like a bug from Facebook

Comment: In `xid` property case I get the following response:
`{
   <url>: {
      "id": <url>,
      "shares": 256,
   }
}`

In `href` property case I get this one:
`{
   <url>: {
      "id": <url>,
      "shares": 120,
      "comments": 1
   }
}`

Comment: In both urls I have facebook comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, it is not possible to merge comments from an XID to an href.